# Calling sprintf in x64 assembly

Tags: assembly, printf, x86-64, nasm, calling-convention

It seems that I can't call `sprintf()` correctly in assembly.

When I try to `dprintf()` my buffer that should now be formatted, all I get is:

```
(null)
```

and a segmentation fault. When running `lldb` with my program, `strlen()` is the reason of the fail as it can't find a `\0` in my buffer.

Here's my code:

```
mov     rdi, buff
mov     rsi, 0
mov     rdx, 17
call    memset
lea     rsi, [rel n_head]
mov     rdx, rax
call    sprintf
mov     rdx, rdi
lea     rsi, [rel fmt]
mov     rdi, 1
call    dprintf

...

section .data
    n_head: db "Low battery: %d%%", 0
    fmt:    db "%s", 10, 0

section .bss
    buff:   resb 17
```

What did I do wrong?

I assemble with `nasm -f elf64` and `clang` with nasm 2.14.02 and llvm 10.0.0 on FreeBSD 12.1-RELEASE amd64.

Comment: Check your calling conventions

Comment: You need to reload `rdi` because it is a caller-saved register.